# What is wrong with java zoneinfo?

Tags: java, timezone

I have a Europe/Moscow timezone in my Mageia 4.

The code like this

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
```

returns

```
Fri Oct 24 13:43:22 GMT+03:00 2014
GMT+03:00
```

if I set the system date in 24.10.2014

and that code returns

```
Sun Oct 26 14:44:26 GMT+03:00 2014
GMT+03:00
```

if I set the system date in 26.10.2014

In my point of view it is wrong behavior of java zoneinfo system.
I downloaded the tzupdater and run it, the file Europe/Moscow was updated and now its size is 705 kB.

I try the code below:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
                System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
                System.out.println(java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());
```

and it returns

```
Fri Oct 24 15:10:34 MSK 2014
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Moscow",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=79,lastRule=null]
```

and

```
Sun Oct 26 15:32:03 MSK 2014
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Moscow",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=79,lastRule=null]
```

Why so? Why the offset is the same in these two cases?

Comment: Did tzupdater show which version it was updating to?

Comment: Hang on - if your `user.timezone` value is just "GMT+03:00" then yes, it will always show GMT+03:00... because it's *not* using `Europe/Moscow`. So it's a matter of where `user.timezone` is being populated, rather than the current database...

Comment: tzupdater update zones in 2014i version.

Comment: The offset in the string representation is the standard offset. What are you trying to achieve here? What's the real problem? You shouldn't be using the result of calling `TimeZone.toString()`... There *may* be other issues, but you're not currently showing them. (For example, you might want to create a `Date` object for October 24th and find the UTC offset for that `Date` - *that* would be a useful test.)

Comment: The problem was solved by defining the default Timezone by using the TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow")) . But I just want to understand why does my code'Date date = new Date(2014,9,24);  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));  System.out.println(date);  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  System.out.println(date);'  returns  'Sat Oct 24 00:00:00 MSK 3914  Fri Oct 23 21:00:00 UTC 3914'  At 24th of october there were UTC+4 hours in Moscow.

Comment: You should put a short but complete program demonstrating the problem *in your question* - and ideally avoid using deprecated constructors of `Date`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your attention, your comment about deprecated method is a key :). It works really weird! When I change the deprecated constructor with this one *Date date = new Date(1414108800000l);* everything starts work fine! Main conclusion about my start question is don't remember to set the correct default timezone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Do not use an offset (`+03:00`) when you mean a time zone (`Europe/Moscow`)
- Never rely on JVM’s current default time zone.
- Never use `java.util.Date`.

For a moment in UTC, use `java.time.Instant`.

```
Instant.now()
```

For a moment in a time zone, use `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Moscow" ) 
)
```

## Offset versus time zone

As the comment by Jon Skeet notes, your JVM’s initial default time zone was not a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone), it was merely an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

What is the difference? An offset is simply a number of hours, minutes, and seconds, positive (ahead of UTC) or negative (behind UTC). A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. The offset for a region can change whenever the politicians so deem. For example, many politicians buy into the lunacy of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), and change the offset twice a year.

So if you set your time zone to a mere offset such as `+03:00` (three hours ahead of UTC/GMT) rather than a time zone such as `Europe/Moscow`, your current date-time will always be reported as three hours ahead of UTC. Changes in offset for your region such as DST will be ignored, because you said so, you said "Always three hours ahead of UTC".

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Instead of `TimeZone`, use `ZoneId`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Moscow" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```

## Avoid setting default time zone

You should only set the default time zone of your JVM as a last-ditch act of desperation.

Setting the default time zone (and default locale, by the way) immediately affects all code in all threads of all apps running within that JVM. You will be rudely changing the zone behind the backs of other programmers. You might even find that their code changes the zone behind *your* back, *during* runtime.

Better to write all your date-time handling to never rely on the current default zone (or locale). Specify explicitly your desired/expected time zone by passing optional arguments. Personally, I wish those time zone arguments were required rather than optional, to help educated programmers about date-time issue.

We can see an example of this in the code above. Notice how we pass a `ZoneId` for Russia to the `now` method. Otherwise, we would be capturing the current moment in the wall-clock time of whatever region happens to be the JVM’s current default time zone.

Tip: If critical, always confirm the time zone with the user.

## `java.util.Date::toString` lies

Be aware that the `toString` method on the `Date` objects you were calling has the anti-feature of dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text to represent that moment. While well-intentioned, this unfortunate design decision has confused countless programmers trying to wrangle date-time values in Java. A `java.util.Date` is actually in UTC, as a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC. The time zone shown in the string is not actually in the `Date` object.

But this is moot, as this is one of *many* reasons to avoid this class entirely. Use `java.util.Instant` instead. Instead of `GregorianCalendar`, use `ZonedDateTime`.

[image: table of date-time classes in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by adding the definition of correct timezone.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
```

Comment: does this method still work for you? Cause I guess we have the same problem and I have tried your solution but it didn't work for me, still get one extra hour...

Comment: Yes I have done it after posting the comment, now it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second test (26.10.2014) is after the change to wintertime so you probably need to correct the time as well by -1 hour