# Why Java is displaying a wrong time (1 hour ahead) even if I have set the timezone?

Tags: java, date, datetime

Hi everyone I have some troubles with the Date object in Java, actually if I instantiate an empty Date instance:

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("Date = " + date);
```

Its value is 23:30 while I am in Moscow and the time here is 22:30.

If I try to use a custom format and set the timezone with a SimpleDataFormat object, like this:

```
Date date = (Date) prop.getValue();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
System.out.println("Date = " + sdf.format(date));
```

I also get an overhead of 1 hour `Date = 23:35` while the correct time where I am is 22:30.

Also the problem is that the default TimeZone of my JVM is set correctly:

```
System.out.println("TIMEZONE : " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

Actaully outputs `TIMEZONE : Europe/Moscow`

So actually, where is the problem?

**EDIT**: I have found a solution, just look at my answer below.

Comment: That's because Moscow is Asia and not Europe. And Putin - khuilo, la-la-la-la-la.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, so take this with a gran of salt, Russia changed from permanent daylight savings time to permanent standard time; just this year.

Comment: I had similar experience one time (not with java/JVM language), the problem was about DST, it might be something worth checking too.

Comment: Yes I know that there were changes http://news.yahoo.com/russia-abandons-round-daylight-saving-time-135222141.html But now how should I interpret the results the JVM is giving me? It looks like the JVM is not up to date, doesn't it?

Comment: @nikoliazekter, subtract 1? So it will be forever? JVM Date will always have an extra hour for the Europe/Moscow timezone?

Comment: You know i can't predict the future. I have just tested time here in Ukraine and for Moscow. It gives right time for Ukraine and wrong time in Moscow, 1 hour ahead as you mentioned. It's sanction from Oracle, lol.

Comment: Ahah, I hope it is not so.

Comment: Have you read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674248/what-is-wrong-with-java-zoneinfo ?

Comment: Thank you for the link, the OP says that he has resolved with `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));`, I have tried it but I still get `Sun Dec 14 00:37:13 MSK 2014` because of the overhead, while now is 23:37 in Moscow`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
  System.out.println(new java.util.Date());`

Comment: Anyway I have resolved, if you are interested, check my edit!

Comment: @user3019105 You should add your solution to an answer and accept it. It is perfecty fine to answer your own questions like this and makes it easier to read the site.

Comment: All right I'll do it right now!

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Tends to be released with updates to the tz database. Also vastly superior to the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found how to resolve this issue.

1) Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html

2) Download the .zip, unzip it, close all java applications currently running, go to the **tzupdater-1.4.9-2014i** folder

3) Open a command line shell and type:

```
$ java -jar tzupdater.jar -u
```

Root privilege might be required.

After that, restart the Java applications, and now:

```
 System.out.println(new GregorianCalendar().getTime());
 System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
```

Both will output `Sun Dec 14 00:02:59 MSK 2014`, which is the correct current time in Moscow, no extra hour!